# Getting current Object in Control template

Tags: wpf, listview, controltemplate

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,28,0" Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{Binding IsEditable,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
                                            <TextBlock Foreground="Gray" Text="{Binding DateCreated,Converter={StaticResource DateTimeConverter}}" FontFamily="/Assets/Fonts/Berthold Akzidenz Grotesk BE Regular.ttf" FontSize="16"/>
                                            <TextBlock Text=":" Foreground="Gray"/>
                                            <TextBlock Width="20"/>
                                            <TextBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"  BorderThickness="0" Name="TrainerNoteText" Text="{Binding TrainerNote}" FontFamily="/Assets/Fonts/Berthold Akzidenz Grotesk BE Regular.ttf" Foreground="Black" FontSize="16" TextWrapping="Wrap" KeyUp="EditTrainerNote" Width="400"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </ControlTemplate>
```

The above control template is in a listview. The textbox inside is editable. So when user presses the enter key, I need to get the current object associated with that. How to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by 'the current object associated with [the `TextBox`]'? Do you mean the `ListBoxItem`? Can I ask what you need that for? There might be another way to do what you want also.

Comment: yes the list box item

Comment: My list box is associated with a list. However , the listbox item can be edited by the user on the UI. So when the user edits the textbox and presses enter i need to update my object and save that in the database. So if there is any better way, you can tell me that as well

Comment: You know, you really should define what your items look like in a `DataTemplate` defined in the [`ListBox.ItemTemplate` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx) and *not* the `ListBoxItem.Template` property.

Comment: Ok I'll make the change. Any reason why I should do that? Also, still my question remains unanswered, how would still get the current object binded to that listviewitem when the user makes some changes in the textbox

Comment: Saving to database should happen in ViewModel and not in View. Listening to events in ListBoxItem is the wrong way. Better listen in property setter in ViewModel or even better use wpf commands.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to KeyDown RoutedEvent at ListView level.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.keydown.aspx

Its an attached event and its handler can be placed anywhere in VisualTree.

Here is an example:

```
<StackPanel TextBox.KeyDown="OnKeyDownHandler">
  <TextBox Width="300" Height="20"/>
</StackPanel>
```

And this is the handler:

```
public void OnKeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Return)
    {
        TextBox tbx = (TextBox)sender;
        tbx.....
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't make myself clear earlier sorry. I need to get the object that is binded with the listviewitem which contains the textbox which is being edited

Comment: Same thing. Listen to handler. When handler called cast to TextBox and get BindingExpression out of TextBox.Text poperty. When you get BindingExpression you can access source or target properties.

Comment: @devhedgehog, the user is already handling the `KeyUp` event, although it is quite hard to see that as the code is not formatted well. Also, he wants to access the `ListBoxItem`, not the `TextBox`.

Comment: @Sheridan I thought he wants to hande it at the top. I misunderstood him. If he wants to access ListBoxItem he just needs to move handler at ListBoxItem level and sender will be associated ListBoxItem. e.OriginalSource would be still the TextBox which originally triggered event.

Comment: Yes, I didn't understand what he wanted at first either. However, I think that he just needs to properly data bind his properties rather than handling events.

Answer (score 0):

You know, you really should define what your items look like in a `DataTemplate` defined in the [`ListBox.ItemTemplate` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx) and *not* the `ListBoxItem.Template` property. Based on the example from the linked page:

```
<ListBox Width="400" Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollectionProperty}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TaskName}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Priority}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

When `Binding` a collection property to the `ListBox.Items` property, all of the UI elements inside the `DataTemplate` will have access to the properties of the type that is in the collection. In this example, the type that populates the `YourCollectionProperty` collection has `TaskName`, `Description` and `Priority` properties in it. You can replace these properties with those from the type that is in *your* collection property.

If you set up your properties to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface (or use `DependencyProperties` then any updates in the UI elements will *automatically* be updated in the data objects in the view model/code behind. Therefore, there is no need to add `KeyDown` or `KeyUp` handlers. For more information, please read the [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) page on MSDN.

Comment: Yup, DataTemplates are great suggestion. +1